# Issue with matplotlib where subplots are overwritten

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am having trouble with formatting my matplotlib figure, I am trying to take in several subfigures and then graph them to a single figure. What I get instead is the figures overlap and graph on the the same axis rather than being plotted to a different axis. I have attached an image of the corresponding figure as well as the code snippets below. I had based my code off this example by matplotlib for creating [subfigures](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subfigures.html)

This is what I have in my main file

```
fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True, figsize=(14, 5))
subfigs = fig.subfigures(1, 2, wspace=0.07)

axsLeft = subfigs[0].subplots(3, 1)
for ax in enumerate(axsLeft):
    pc = plot_acceleration(recording_df, recording_id)

axsRight = subfigs[1].subplots(3, 1)
for ax in enumerate(axsRight):
    pc = plot_gyroscope(recording_df, recording_id)

fig.suptitle("Figures for Times", fontsize="xx-large")

plt.show()
```

And then in a separate python file I have the following functions that are being called from the code snippet above:

```
def plot_acceleration(data_df: pd.DataFrame, recording_id: str):
    skipping a lot of other code...

    fig = plt.figure(1)

    plt.subplot(3, 1, 1)
    plt.title(recording_id + "\nAcceleration versus time")

    plt.subplot(3, 1, 2)
    plt.plot(time, y_accel, ".-")

    plt.subplot(3, 1, 3)
    plt.plot(time, z_accel, ".-")

    return fig


def plot_gyroscope(data_df: pd.DataFrame, recording_id: str):
    skipping a lot of other code...

    fig = plt.figure(1)

    plt.subplot(3, 1, 1)
    plt.plot(time, x_gyro, ".-")


    plt.subplot(3, 1, 2)
    plt.plot(time, y_gyro, ".-")


    plt.subplot(3, 1, 3)
    plt.plot(time, z_gryo, ".-")

    return fig
```

From what I understand it must be an issue with the `fig = plt.figure(1)` lines in both functions but I can't figure out what to do resolve it, I don't think I can try to return subplots because that might not be correct.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You handle the plot related objects both in the main code and in the functions and there is no communication, so your plotting functions just recreate new figures.

You should reorganize your code to have the plotting function not handle any figure related level but rather get sub-elements on which to plot passed as parameters.

Below is dummy code to illustrate my point:

```
def plot_acceleration(data, subfig):
    # do something with subfig directly, not recreating new figure

fig = plt.figure(...)
subfigs = fig.subfigures(...)

for subfig in subfigs:
    plot_acceleration(data, subfig)
```

Comment: Hi! I tried your recommendation but it still doesn't work! I created a function that would pass in the subfigures in but it still does not graph them properly.